# All writable and executable program memory segment types

Tags: c++, c, linux, security, memory

In "Secure coding in C and C++", the author mentions,

"The W^X policy allows a memory segment to be writable or executable, but no both. This policy cannot prevent overwriting targets such as those required by atexit() that need to be both writable at runtime and executable. "

I have two questions:

1. The atexit needs to register a function by a function pointer as argument. The function pointed by the function pointer is either defined in the current program where linker will find the definition or the runtime loader will finds the function body. In either cases, we will know the function definition. Then it only needs to be executable. So why the memory segment for atexit() needs to be both writable at runtime and executable?
2. Can any C/C++ expert tells me that what other types of APIs that have this property (writable at runtime and executable)? (let's limit the scope to linux only)

Comment: Lazy JITers might use W|X segments. They *shouldn't*, but they're lazy.

Comment: I agree with you about exit handlers.  The list of *pointers to* exit handler functions needs to be writable, but does not need to be executable. The pointed to *functions* need to be executable, but they do not need to be in writable segments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, memory that can be written AND executed is very easily tempered with and can result in exploits more easily since there is no need to use ROP or other fancy methods, you can simply write anywhere in the segment the code to execute and branch to it.
In your quote, the meaning of targets in this context is very likely to be a list of function pointers called on exit. The list itself needs to be writable/mutable as per the C API. The code these functions point to need only be executable. Here again, because the list is mutable, you could exploit a program by simply modifying this list by inserting a pointer to your code and force the program to exit which would execute your code. In this context, keeping all memory segments writable OR executable will not save you since 2 different segments are used here (one writable with the function pointer list, the other executable with the code).

Writable & executable memory segments are required by anything that generates code dynamically at runtime: JIT, kernel, executable unpackers, etc. For each of these, there is no technical requirement that the segments hold both properties at the same time. The memory can be allocated writable first, the code copied/generated and with a call to mprotect(), be made executable (and removing the writable property). The only scenario I can see that would benefit from having both properties at the same time is perhaps in a memory constrained environment (eg: unpack an executable in place).

Note that some platforms do not support executable memory to be allocated in user space: Xbox360 & PS3 for example do not support JIT. (The kernel/api support it but you will not be able to release your software, Microsoft and Sony will refuse your submissions as such a feature can only be used in development.)

Comment: At the same time, if Linux (Unices) allow you to call `mprotect()` to change the current flags, then you can easily end up with any memory area as executable. Of course, it's harder for hackers to generate a valid call to `mprotect()` first... If your compiler is written to be safe at execution time, then you are fine. For that, I guess a lot of people should not write such software, ever. :-)